# gcloud ssh jobs when internet in interrupted

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I'm using google cloud instance for one of my long duration job and using : gcloud compute ssh 'instance name' to connect from one of my ubuntu PC terminal.

All goes well. But as the job takes few hours to complete and when my PC is out of network the shell gets killed and hence the job also.

I'm wondering if there is a way by which the job can continue on google cloud when the 'SSH terminal' from my PC gets killed because on network unavailability?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking into some persistent methods/programs which utilize SSH. Not sure if you'll need to, but it's easy enough just to SSH to one of your instances in gcloud without using the sdk commands. One option is to check out a program like https://mosh.org Another is to write a small script or use Screen to enable a persistent session. Info on writing that script can be found here https://michael.lustfield.net/linux/persistent-ssh

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, screen and raw ssh(instead of sdk) worked!

Answer (score 1):

The best answer here is to use [mosh](http://mosh.org) to connect to your instance.  In order to do this, you will need to first install mosh on your instance via the normal method for your distribution.  Second you will need to modify the firewall that Google runs to allow for the required UDP port to reach:

```
you@local-pc:~$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-mosh --allow=udp:60001
```

In this case we use the name 'default-allow-mosh' following the nomenclature used in the rest of the firewall rules of *network*-*action*-*what* and telling it to allow the UDP port that mosh says it must have allowed through.